# Should we always nullcheck Context inside a fragment?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-context

I have a very simple on click listener in my fragment:

```
button?.setOnClickListener {
    val intent = Intent(MyActivity.createIntent(context!!)) // crash here because context is null
    startActivity(intent)
}
```

Crashlytics shows that some users are getting `KotlinNullPointerException` crashes when clicking on this specific button. Now I know the problem is happening because I am force unwrapping the Context. If I simply wrapped it inside a nullcheck, it would not crash.

But I assume that there's a bigger underlying issue in my code because I always force unwrap context when I need it and I only have issues with this specific piece of code.

What's the rule here? Should we **always** nullcheck our Context or not?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you will look at the source code of `fragment.getContext()` method, you will see:

```
@Nullable
public Context getContext() {
    return mHost == null ? null : mHost.getContext();
}
```

Which means that `getContext` can return `null`. Internally `mHost` represents an `Activity` fragment is attached to. Fragment isn't always attached to it's hosting activity, you can observe this using `onAttach` / `onDetach` lifecycle callbacks.

In your case, as already mentioned, best approach would be to use context from a `View`

```
view.setOnClickListener { it.context }
```

But in general, always check nullable things, and don't do `!!` even if you're sure it is not `null`. In such way you will have less error prone code, providing an alternative way of handling `null`s.

Answer (score 1):

Inside button click you can easily use : `view.getContext()` to get the context *or in Kotlin*

```
it.context // which will be never null
```

i.e,

```
button?.setOnClickListener {
   val intent = Intent(MyActivity.createIntent(it.context)) // this wont ever crash
   startActivity(intent)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

most propably you will be okay with code like that

```
button?.setOnClickListener {startActivity(MyActivity.createIntent(it.context))}
```

I believe on your MyActivity.createIntent() fun you return Intent